# Getting value of input field using variable as name in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var count='0';
var value= document.getElementsByName('test['+count+']').value;
alert('test['+count+']');
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="test[0]">
```

```js
var count='0';
var value= document.getElementsByName('test['+count+']').value;
alert(value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="test[0]">
```

Can't get the value of the field in javascript..By checking the above u get the difference..I am passing the name correctly..eventhough it shows undefined value..Just a beginner in javascript..help me solving this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByName returns list of matching name elements. you need to specify index of element you want to access.
like this `document.getElementsByName('test['+count+']')[0].value;`

```js
var count='0';
var value= document.getElementsByName('test['+count+']')[0].value;
alert(value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="test[0]">
```

Comment: thanks for the solution..Dinesh..:-)

Comment: @Learner glad  it helped you.